# Standby versus autopoweroff

Tags: battery, sleep-wake, power, power-management

From the `pmset` manpage:

> STANDBY ARGUMENTS
>
> ```
>  standby causes kernel power management to automatically hibernate a machine after it
>  has slept for a specified time period. This saves power while asleep. This setting
>  defaults to ON for supported hardware. The setting standby will be visible in pmset
>  -g if the feature is supported on this machine.
>
>  standbydelayhigh and standbydelaylow specify the delay, in seconds, before writing
>  the hibernation image to disk and powering off memory for Standby.  standbydelayhigh
>  is used when the remaining battery capacity is above highstandbythreshold , and
>  standbydelaylow is used when the remaining battery capacity is below
>  highstandbythreshold.
>
>  highstandbythreshold has a default value of 50 percent.
>
>  autopoweroff is enabled by default on supported platforms as an implementation of Lot
>  6 to the European Energy-related Products Directive. After sleeping for
>  <autopoweroffdelay> seconds, the system will write a hibernation image and go into a
>  lower power chipset sleep. Wakeups from this state will take longer than wakeups from
>  regular sleep.
>
>  autopoweroffdelay specifies the delay, in seconds, before entering autopoweroff mode.
> ```

What's the difference? Both settings, standby and autopoweroff, control when the machine goes into the sleep mode configured with `hibernatemode`, correct?

standbydelaylow and standbydelayhigh do so with respect to the current battery capacity, while autopoweroffdelay is simply a timer. Why are there these two concurrent ways to do this? How should I configure these settings in a way that makes sense?

Comment: autopoweroff is for regulatory requirements. It must be enabled by default when computer is shipped in EU. There are strict requirements which are not easy to meet (therefore "Wakeups from this state will take longer than wakeups from regular sleep."). Computers should not consume more than 0.5 W in this state ([Energy Consumption for products with standby and off-mode](https://ec.europa.eu/info/energy-climate-change-environment/standards-tools-and-labels/products-labelling-rules-and-requirements/energy-label-and-ecodesign/energy-efficient-products/mode-standby-and-networked-standby_en))

Comment: This is there for purely burocratical reasons? How should I deal with it then?